# In Excel, how to return name associated with max value in a column?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, max, vlookup

I have text information in columns A through H. I have numerical data in columns I onward. My goal is to find the maximum numerical value in all columns I and onward, and return the corresponding name from column H.

For example, the maximum number in column J is 0.382, located at J88. So I want Excel to return the text content of H88.

I tried doing VLOOKUP but it seems like this was only working if my column of names/text is adjacent to my column of numerical values, so that was a dead end.

Comment: Have you looked in to INDEX/MATCH?

Answer (score 1):

What you need is combination of INDEX() and MATCH():

```
=INDEX(H:H;MATCH(MAX(J:J);J:J;0))
```

This formula finds position of the highest value in the J:J column than returns cell on the same position in the H:H column.

VLOOKUP() doesn't work in this case because you need to mind order of the columns with the function, if you swapped them it would work just fine.

Comment: Thank you for providing that formula! I had looked at and discarded MATCH but I see that I was wrong!

Answer (score 0):

Just to elaborate on @M.Douda's answer, since it may not be clear that this approach can cause unintended mistakes if you have more than one maximum.

`index()` and `match()` is definitely the way to go, but you need to be careful if there is more than one maximum (i.e. if both J88 and J89 have a value of 0.382). With the `match_type` parameter equal to 0, values can be in any order and Excel will return the first match of the search, but only that one.

Note: If you wanted to keep using `vlookup()`, a simple solution would be to add one column in the end (to the right) where you copy from column H (but this is obviously redundant, not recommended). It also suffers from the maxima problem.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the "maxima problem"?

Comment: By "maxima problem" I'm just referring to the fact that Index+Match or Vlookup do not return more than one value. Let's say that you are trying to determine the employee of the month (names in column H) based on sales (values in column J). Imagine there were two employees that sold the same amount. Only the first would be spotted, but your Index+Match approach would not let you know that. Whenever I use Index+Match to determine the maximum, I always wrap it in an IF formula that counts how many maximum values there are in the range) - just in case...

Comment: That is very helpful-- thank you. I appreciate the suggestion to use an IF formula as well, to be aware of the case of more than one maximum.

Comment: A follow-up question: How can I duplicate this formula in all of the other columns, while still keeping H as the column whose value I'm returning?  For example, I used "=INDEX(H3:H200, MATCH(MAX(J3:J200),J3:J200,0))" and it correctly returned the value I wanted. But if I paste that formula in the K column, it becomes, "=INDEX(I3:I200, MATCH(MAX(K3:K200),K3:K200,0))". You can see the reference is now the I column, but I want it to remain the H column. I understand why this happened but I don't know how to overcome it.

Comment: Nevermind, I found that I can use "$H$3: $H$200...." to keep the reference the same. Thanks again for the help.